# When I apply a load anywhere in the gym the power offsets dramatically. What can cause it?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, troubleshooting

After a storm they returned to the gym and the lights were flickering which prompted them to contact me after evaluating the panel with the breakers on the reading at the feeders in the panel and main disconnect were reading Leg 1 233volts Leg 2 30volts. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Where on this spinning globe are you?  It really helps us to give you the best answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds very much like a commercial application. Unfortunately, this site is for Home Improvement, and therefore, commercial questions are off-topic.

Comment: Someone who works for a commercial electrical contractor shouldn’t be asking random people on the internet for advice.

Comment: Assuming you are in a country which uses 120V electricity, you almost certainly have a lost neutral.

Comment: Yikes, you should consider not using your company logo as an avatar and don't use your real name.

Comment: This should **not** have been closed as off-topic. It should have been closed as **duplicate** with any of the numerous **LOST NEUTRAL** posts, because that sounds like *exactly* what is happening here. Yes, it is a commercial building. I don't care! The problem is the same in any small building with a lost neutral.   DeAndre - **CALL YOUR UTILITY AND TELL THEM YOU HAVE AN OUTAGE**. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176807/electrical-issues-in-house-less-than-18-mos-old/176818#176818 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148995/panel-breakers-are-alternately-90-v-and-140-v

Comment: Fair point, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. Knee-jerk reaction on my part. I'd support a vote to reopen, then close as a dupe if you'd care to pursue it.